Why are config properties not loading from application.yml in my Java Spring application?
I'm new to Java, and in my service I can't get properties from an application.yml file. Maybe it is a VS Code problem...
I have configuration properties
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private  String uploadpath;

}

and an application.yml file with content:
application:
 uploadpath: src/main/resources/upload

But in my service:

@Service
public class DocumentService {

    private final IDocumentRepository docRepository;
    private final DocumentExtractorFactory docExtractorFactory;
    private final ConfigProperties props;
    
    public DocumentService (IDocumentRepository docRepository, DocumentExtractorFactory docExtractorFactory, ConfigProperties props){
        this.docRepository=docRepository;
        this.docExtractorFactory= docExtractorFactory;
        this.props = props;
    }

}

ConfigProperties props initializes with uploadpath = null.
I tried option with an annotation the main method:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class)
public class TextractorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication.run(TextractorApplication.class, args);
    }
}

and without @Configuration on the ConfigirationProperties class:
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class ConfigProperties {

...

}

Then I tried make ConfigProperties props @Autowired in DocumentService but this does not work too.
How I can to get properties from the application.yml file?

(1) Provide the package names of each class.  The typical gotcha in this code area is that the class scanner is not looking where you expect it to be looking. (2) intentionally break the syntax in the YAML file to be sure that this file is indeed being read.

TextractorApplication class in package zhiganov.textractor, ConfigProperties class in package zhiganov.textractor.configuration, DocumentService class in package zhiganov.textractor.service. File application.yml locating in resources folder and I had checked it syntax by online validator

with following setup it should work:
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class ConfigProperties {

    private String uploadpath;
}

And in your service:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class TestService {

    private final ConfigProperties configProperties;

    public void test() {
        System.out.println(configProperties.getUploadpath());
    }

}


I had tried this, but its useless for my situation

Why wouldn't it?
What is your situation?

I don't know but it is not works. Now I creating new project and recreating all classes. I hope it is break building process in VS Code

Re-creating the project with all classes helped. Perhaps due to the fact that at some point I deleted the line from the project name from the yml file and also tried to integrate the module into the project, something broke...
